# How to pass multiple parameters in url using php

Tags: php, html

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sem = $_POST['semester'];
        $sess = $_POST['session'];
         $sexam = $_POST['exam'];
         $_SESSION['sem'] = $sem;
         $_SESSION['sess'] = $sess;
         $_SESSION['exa'] = $sexam;}?>

       <a href="print.php?id=<?php echo 
       array($_SESSION['sem'],$_SESSION['sess'],$_SESSION['exam']);  ?>" 
        target="_blank" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</a>
```

How can I pass these SESSION variables in URL to another page?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a session specific set of variables, i.e., you don't need to send them via URL or any other method, they are help on you server (local or remote). You just need to make sure the session has been started (`session_start();`)

Comment: Session already started in both pages but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to add session variables to the URL? And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Ok... then tell me how to pass multiple variables without using Sessions, in the URL?

Comment: HTML forms, using proper request params. Session is intended for things that are user specific cache (such as ID & username or permissions maybe)

Comment: Show your code including session_start on both pages please.

Comment: _“Session already started in both pages but it doesn't work.”_ - well then debug why it doesn’t, instead of trying to come up with such nonsense workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages. Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.

So; Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

Start a PHP Session

Page 1:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that session variables are not passed individually to each new page, instead they are retrieved from the session we open at the beginning of each page `session_start()`.

Refer this tutorial:
[PHP 5 Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use $_SESSION variable

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $sem = $_POST['semester'];
    $sess = $_POST['session'];
    $sexam = $_POST['exam'];
    $_SESSION['sem'] = $sem;
    $_SESSION['sess'] = $sess;
    $_SESSION['exa'] = $sexam;

    $urlFromSession = "semester={$_SESSION['sem']}&session={$_SESSION['sess']}&exam={$_SESSION['exa']}";
    $urlFromPost = "semester={$_POST['semester']}&session={$_POST['session']}&exam={$_POST['exam']}";
}
?>

<a href="print.php?<?= $urlFromSession ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Post - urlFromSession</a><br/>

<a href="print.php?<?= $urlFromPost ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Post - urlFromPost</a><br/>
```

URL will be something like this **print.php?semester=test&session=test&exam=test**

You will get parameters inside print.php page

```
<?php
echo $_GET['semester'];
echo $_GET['session'];
echo $_GET['exam'];
```